# SDK problem with installation

Tags: android

Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml, reason: Permission denied: connect

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Settings` select `Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://...` , looks like your Windows doesn't have `OpenSSL` installed.